# How to prevent Google Voice number linking to your Google+ full name and image?

Tags: google-plus, privacy, google-contacts, google-voice, google-hangouts

I recently noticed that my Google contacts started showing pictures and full names of some contacts, presumably because they were using Google Voice. I added myself as a contact, merely as 'X' with my G-Voice number to a second G-account. As expected, my full name and Google+ profile image came up in that second account's address book. I presume this can be avoided by some deep setting in G+, or may have something to do with Hangouts. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

Disable [help friends find you by phone number](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3113316) and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks! Would you have any idea how long it takes for this to be effective? That is, if in someone else's G-Contacts, if my full name has been listed before this was unchecked, will G-Contacts remove my name at some point?

Comment: I think that unless someone has manually entered your phone number in their contacts list your name should stop showing up. I don't know how long it would take though.